# Random logic engine implementation ideas

Tags: algorithm, random

I try to find an effective random logic algorithm for this scenario. It doesn't matter which programming Language:
Say I have 20 element array filled with numbers

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
```

From this I need to construct each time 15 size array BUT 
each time I set numbers that must be in this new array, and the remaining slots will be filled with random numbers from the master array.
For example:
In the new array the numbers that must be in are: `1,11,13,20,8,9`
so the new array will be:

```
[1,N,N,11,N,20,8,N,9,N,N,N,13,N,N]
```

Where the `N`s are random numbers from ALL 20 elements of the Master array.

Another example:
given `2,18,17,9,5` 
create new 10 element array:

```
[2,2,18,2,11,17,20,5,5,9]
```

No problem with duplicate elements

I'm trying to find some good algorithm for this.

Comment: Are there any other constraints? From what you describe, it seems you can just fill all the other slots with elements drawn randomly from the master array.

Comment: Every language I know provides a `random` function, whose result may be easily clamped to a specific range if it doesn't support that already. Are you asking for an alternate implementation of `random`? Or is it the distribution of the fixed values within the new array which is a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to receive one random number at a time and don't want to create the full `result` array up front, an alternative to my other answer is this:

1. Get a random number ranging from 0..`requested_number` (where `requested_number` is the total number of elements to fetch).
2. If this index is between 0 and `length(required)`, print it from the array `required`; then *remove* it from the array;
3. .. else the next index is > `length(required)` and so pick any random number out of the `optional` array.
4. Decrease `requested_number` and repeat until this reaches 0.

You need **2** calls to `random`; the first to select an index from `total_number - required_number`, so you know from which array to pick a value, and the second time for `optional`, to pick a random number out of the entire available range.

Here is a basic implementation in C (footnote: using `mod` on `rand()` does not yield A Good Random Number, but it'll do for this example).

```c
int main()
{
    int optional[] = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20 };
    int required[] = { 21,22,23,24,25 };
    int requested_number = 15;

    int take_from_required, optional_size, next;

    srand(time(NULL));

    if (requested_number < sizeof(required)/sizeof(required[0]))
    {
        printf ("requested number of elements must be at least as large as required array\n");
        return EDOM;
    }

/*  Use this much from 'required': */
    take_from_required = sizeof(required)/sizeof(required[0]);
/*  Use this much from 'optional': */
    optional_size = sizeof(optional)/sizeof(optional[0]);

    while (requested_number > 0)
    {
        /* Please note this is a fairly bad 'random'!
            As discussed many times before on SO. */
        next = rand() % requested_number;

        /* Take from which array? */
        if (next >= take_from_required)
        {
            printf ("%d\n", optional[rand() % optional_size]);
        } else
        {
            printf ("%d (required)\n", required[next]);
            required[next] = required[take_from_required-1];
            take_from_required--;
        }
        requested_number--;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, this is the issue:

```
optional [ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20 ]
required [ 2,18,17,9,5 ]
```

Now construct a new array containing at least all elements of `required`, and filled to its capacity with elements taken from `optional`.

The problem *seems* to be that you need to take out random numbers from either `required` or `optional` and at the same time make sure `required` is empty at the end. [*]

Create a new array `result` (which needs to be at least as long as `required` -- then again, that can be inferred from the question). Copy all elements of `required` into it; fill the rest with random elements from `optional`.

At this point, you fulfill the primary condition, but the elements of `required` always appear first. So, as a last step, shuffle the elements now stored in the `result` array (for example, with the well-known [Fisher-Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle)).

---

[*] 'Empty', because all numbers in `required` *must* be used at least once. Taking them "out" of the array is the easiest way to make sure this happens. Things start to get complicated when (a) you *may* have duplicates of any number (from both `optional` and `required`) **and** (b) `required` is **not a subset** of `optional`.

Comment: good idea for another array, any good recommendation for random algorithm ?